# Why isn't throttle working?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am creating a auto complete box with `rx`.  Here is my code:

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');
var keypresses = Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup');

var searchResults = keypresses.
    throttle(100).
    map(key => {
        return getResults(input.value);
    }).
    switchLatest();

let results = document.getElementById('results');
searchResults.forEach(resultSet => results.value = resultSet);
```

This is making an `http` call to `wikipedia`.  I would expect `throttle` to only send through data if I wait `100 ms` between `keyup`'s, but it is sending an `http` request with each `keyup`.

You can see in the `image` that it is making a separate call with each `keypress`.

[image: chrome console]

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get `throttle` to do what I expect it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it `Rx.Observable.prototype.debounce` you are looking for? Cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/debounce.md.

It says : `Ignores values from an observable sequence which are followed by another value within a computed debounced duration.`

Truth is `debounce` and `throttle` are easily confused, hope that it is what you are looking for. In Rxjs 2, the semantics are actually reversed, so check the version that you are using and the corresponding documentation.

Actually you can also have a look here for an example of `debounce` for autocompletion with Rxjs : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js